# Loading xml data using jQuery and ajax?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I'm, trying to load som data from an xml file using jQuery and ajax but i don't anything back from the ajax request.

The xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<items>
  <item key="NewSite">Create new site</item>
  <item key="EditSite">Edit site</item>
  <item key="DeleteSite">Delete site</item>
  <item key="ViewSite">View site</item>
  <item key="ViewSiteList">View full site list</item>
</items>
```

The jQuery

```
var createsite = "";

//--- get trasnlated text for the notify box
$.ajax({
    url: "/Areas/Admin/Content/Scripts/admin/da-DK.xml",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);

        $xml.find('item').each(function () {
            createsite = $(this).attr("CreateSite").text();
        });

        console.log(createsite);
    }
});
```

But the console log is empty. What am I missing here ?

/Martin

Comment: You are missing an examination of the Net tab of your browser's developer tools, and an `error` handler.

Comment: Why are you passing an XMLDOM to `parseXML` (which expects a string)?

Comment: What am I looking for at the Net tab and I do not get any errors. parseXML was from an example I found on the web.

Comment: When you specify `dataType` it'll turn returned data as that specific type so you don't need to parse it. If you still have problem, take a look at `xml` to check whether it's been filled or not.

Comment: That makes sence, thank you. And the xml returns fine in the console. Then I just need to know how to check for the key="NewSite" so that I kan get the text from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an error in your code, ***$(this).attr("CreateSite")*** can be null so ***$(this).attr("CreateSite").text()*** throws an exception. Below is the corrected code:

```
 var createsite = "";

    //--- get trasnlated text for the notify box
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Areas/Admin/Content/Scripts/admin/da-DK.xml",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
            $xml = $(xmlDoc);

            $xml.find('item').each(function () {
               if($(this).attr("CreateSite")){
                  createsite=  $(this).text();
                }
            });

            console.log("createsite=>"+createsite);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("call failled");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well $(this).text(); returns the text from all of the nodes but I need to get the one where key has a specific value like key="CreateSite" how do I achieve that?

Comment: you just need to change the test:
  **if($(this).attr("key")=="xxx"){
        createsite=  $(this).text();
   }**

xxx: the key value to search